# Using WebUnit with ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, automation

Is it possible to use `OpenWebPage` from `WebUnit` in `ParallelTable`? For example such as in:

```
Needs["WebUnit`"]
InstallWebUnit[]
StartWebSession[];

pages = {"www.wolfram.com", ... }
ParallelTable[
  OpenWebPage[pages[[i]]];
  html = GetPageHtml[];
  , {i, Length@pages}
  ]
```

I can start multiple browsing windows by running several `StartWebSession[]` but then how to dedicate a single window to each core?

Comment: This is a question that I am certain the answer is yes to, having modified the source code for `WebUnit` for my own purposes at various points, but Arnoud would be best able to answer. Try asking on Wolfram Community as I expect he spends more time there. As a first, clumsy attempt try a ``ParallelEvaluate[Needs["WebUnit`"];InstallWebUnit[];StartWebSession[]]``. I believe you can do all this from a single web session though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'll ask. Your solution opens a lot of windows; do you know how to close a browser window? `StopWebSession` does not and I did not see any similar commands in the doc.

Comment: I can’t remember off the top of my head and don’t have the time to dig now, but I believe if you dig a bit there’s a way to get the process ID which you could kill (I don’t think it uses ProcessObject) or alternately I think there’s a way to tell it to close itself. I certainly have done it but can’t remember how.

Comment: @b3m2a1 OK thank you. Anyway that's probably so much less efficient than a clean approach. I'll update if I get anything interesting.

Comment: Cross-posting : http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1250232